# PyTorch training script abruptly stops without any warning or error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run a training script in PyTorch for a model with 3dCNN and LSTM, but it abruptly stops after the 1st or 2nd batch. The script was earlier written for just the 3DCNN.

What could be the reason for this?

There is no error or warning messages. I have checked for all system exit statements, but none of them seem to be responsible. I have adjusted batch-size and checked, in case of a memory shortage issue as well.

The training completes the first batch but the model seems to not return any output in the second batch, causing the script to abruptly stop. How to possibly find what is causing this issue?

This is the architecture of the model I am trying to train:

```
def __init__(self, num_classes):
    super(ConvLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.conv_layer1 = self._make_conv_layer(3, 64, (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2))
    self.conv_layer2 = self._make_conv_layer(64, 128, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))
    self.conv_layer3 = self._make_conv_layer(128, 256, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))
    self.conv_layer4 = self._make_conv_layer(256, 256, (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2))

    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=256, hidden_size=512, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)

    self.fc5 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
    self.fc5_act = nn.ELU()
    self.fc6 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

def _make_conv_layer(self, in_c, out_c, pool_size, stride):
    conv_layer = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(in_c, out_c, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm3d(out_c),
        nn.ELU(),
        nn.MaxPool3d(pool_size, stride=stride, padding=0)
    )
    return conv_layer

def forward(self, x):
    # print(f"input {x.size()}")
    x = self.conv_layer1(x)
    x = self.conv_layer2(x)
    x = self.conv_layer3(x)
    x = self.conv_layer4(x)
    
    x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4).contiguous()
    batch_size, seq_len, input_size, height, width = x.size()
    x = x.view(batch_size, seq_len, -1)
    
    lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
    lstm_out = lstm_out[:, -1, :]

    x = self.fc5(lstm_out)
    x = self.fc5_act(x)
    x = self.fc6(x)
    return x
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. without it is very difficult to answer your question. Sometimes in the exercise of building a reproducible example you find the issue, it's a great exercise. Also, having more information would be desirable. For instance, are you running this in GPU? Which one?

Comment: No, not running the training on GPU.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you're running out of memory. Sometimes the operating system is configured to automatically kill memory-intensive processes when the system is close to running out, and when this happens, there wouldn't necessarily be an error message printed to the terminal (although such a message would be recorded in a system log somewhere).

Note that batch size would affect GPU memory usage, but not necessarily CPU memory usage. Also note that memory usage can [grow over time](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13246#issuecomment-905703662) as more data has to be copied between data loader processes.

My first step to debug this would either be to find the relevant system logs, or to just monitor memory usage while the program is running (e.g. with `htop` or something).

Comment: Will look into the memory usage, thanks!